# Remove qty_invoice Programmatically from product on order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice

I'm trying to remove the qty_invoice amount for the products on the order

```
$incrementId = 300085393;

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $item->setData('qty_invoiced', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that is looking. had to `add ->save()` to the end to save it to the DB properly.

```
$incrementId = 300085393;

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $item->setData('qty_invoiced', 0)->save();
}
```